# Day 1:In HTML mode identifying an element in Application moduller and used in object flow. In day 2 BP cannot no longer identify the same element?

Tags: exception, blueprism, rpa

Day 1:In HTML mode identifying an element in Application modular  and used in object flow. In day 2 BP cannot no longer identify the same element?

Object flow throwing "Element not found Exceptions". Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you spy the element in HTML mode always unchecked the "Parent URL" checkbox from the attribute section because parent URL keeps changing whenever you open the browser

Answer (score 0):

Check the attributes that are changing and un check them.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you uncheck every empty field in App Modeler. And make sure you're not spying any dates or anything dynamic. If so you should use Wild Card ( * ).
And make sure you're using Browser-based Application. Hope it helps.